# is it appropriate to use "yet"

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

For background, here is the story (just example, not real):

I applied for a job but they wanted a person who don't smoke. In my resume I wrote as I don't smoke. They invited me for interview. 1 hour before interview meeting, I smoke a cigar. When I talk with HR manager, He felt that I smell cigar and he asked me a question that I didn't understand.

In that context, my question follows.

Okay, As you see I didn't understand what he is asking, So I wanted to ask him a question to understand what he is asking clearly.

So Can I ask him like:

> Are you asking that I smoke **yet** I wrote I don't smoke on my cv?

This is formal to use?
if so "is it appropriate to use "yet" there or something else you can recommend in place of **yet**?

PS:1 hour ago I was very nervous and a bad guy came to me and said smoking is good for stress so I used to smoke.

Comment: Sorry, we don't offer generic proof-reading services on StackExchange. If you have specific points of the sentence that worry you, please ask about those, and we'll be happy to answer. At a higher level though, I think your command of English will be less important to the HR guy than your honesty.

Comment: Sorry, we don't do proof-reading, nor do we do writing advice. If you have a specific point to ask about, like "Can I use *yet* in this sentence or is there a better word to join things together?" then that's fine: we do take questions about specific difficulties. Please edit this question to make it clear what the particular issue with that sentence actually is.

Comment: @AndrewLeach is it ok now.

Comment: Replace 'yet' with 'even though'.  You should also consider replacing the word 'that'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was already asked on ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel obligated to answer this question. I know some will understand why.

It is very difficult to give you an answer because the situation you "*created*" is not very common.

You didn't understand the interviewer's question clearly and you are just *guessing* he might have asked you about smoking right before the interview because of the cigar smell, you can just ask;

Did you just ask me if I smoked?

[Yet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet) is used "**as a conjunction**" to introduce a statement that adds something to a previous statement and *usually contrasts with it in some way* as defined in Merriam-Webster, but it doesn't look appropriate to use it in your sentence.

After you understand the question, you can explain the reason *why you smoked **even though** you identified yourself as a non-smoker* in your CV

Comment: what about "Are you asking that I smoke as though its written that I don't smoke on my cv?"

Comment: or what about "Are you asking me that I smoke as though I don't smoke according to information on my cv? "

Comment: @MichaelRiva You use "if" because the question is replied with **"Yes or No"**. You don't use a *conjunction, **"that"***. Are you asking if I smoked because my CV shows I am a non-smoker?

Comment: "Are you asking that I smoke as if I don't smoke according to information on my cv? "  is that formal?

Comment: @MichaelRiva You don't use **that**. Please look up "as if" in the dictionary as it is very easy to understand the meaning.